# MySQL lowercase to compare data

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the contents from a row in the database and compare the lowercase version of it to a lowercase version of a user imput to check if it exists in the database:

```
"SELECT `id` FROM `user_accounts` WHERE `username` = '".strtolower($username)."'"
```

How can i get username to be lowercase from mysql?

Comment: `LOWER(username)` Review the [MySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really want case to not matter then you should set the collation of the column to be case-insensitive.

```
mysql> SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'foobar' = 'FoObAr';
+---------------------+
| 'foobar' = 'FoObAr' |
+---------------------+
|                   1 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'fOoBaR' = 'FoObAr';
+---------------------+
| 'fOoBaR' = 'FoObAr' |
+---------------------+
|                   1 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'fOoBaR' = 'FoObAz';
+---------------------+
| 'fOoBaR' = 'FoObAz' |
+---------------------+
|                   0 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I think the default installation of mysql using myisam is already case insensitive

Comment: @iWantSimpleLife: Are you suggesting we assume that the asker has the same configuration that you've looked at? And what if they go to another system that has had the defaults changed?

Comment: That is not correct because can affect future inserts, ```lower(`username`)``` is the correct answer

Answer (score 30):

You use lower(`username`) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower

```
"SELECT `id` FROM `user_accounts` WHERE LOWER(`username`) = '".strtolower($username)."'"
```

Answer (score 5):

As answered above, Ideally this should work,

```
$query = "SELECT `id` 
          FROM `user_accounts` 
          WHERE LOWER(`username`) = '".strtolower($username)."'";
```

but it won't work if the "username" column in "user_accounts" table is defined as VARBINARY. The reason is VARBINARY requires the data to be case sensitive

Answer (score 4):

Using one of the above queries should work just fine but CAUTION! If you have your username column indexed, using LOWER on it will make it so your query doesn't use that index.

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = "SELECT `id` 
          FROM `user_accounts` 
          WHERE LOWER(`username`) = '".strtolower($username)."'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `user_accounts`
WHERE LOWER(`username`)='".strtolower($username)."'";
```

Or Use

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `user_accounts` 
WHERE LCASE(`username`)='".strtolower($username)."'";
```

Both will work the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query to do so:

```
$myquery = "SELECT `id` FROM `user_accounts` WHERE
            LOWER(`username`) = '".strtolower($username)."'"
```

`LOWER` is the SQL function that converts all characters to lower case, just like PHP's `strtolower`

On a side note: You should escape the `$username` using `mysql_real_escape_string` to avoid possible sql injection at that point.

Answer (score -1):

```
"SELECT `id` FROM `user_accounts` WHERE lower(`username`) = '".strtolower($username)."'"
```